# Include a row within a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple view call `D_View`. I am trying to select only items that don't have a sale status. I would also like to only select an apple whether it has a sale status or not. 
How could I do this in 1 query?

```
Select * from D_View where SALE in ('');
Select * from D-View where FRUIT in ('Apple');
```

My attempt would be:

```
Select * from D_View where SALE in ('') and FRUIT in ('Apple');
```

but that would only give me Apples with no SALE status.

Comment: Reason for downvote please, so that I can learn for future questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `or`

```
Select * 
from D_View 
where SALE in ('') 
or FRUIT in ('Apple');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 conditions. They need to be operated by `OR`.
reason being you either want apple with any status `OR` item who doesn't have sale status.

query :

```
Select * 
from D_View 
where 
SALE in ('') or FRUIT in ('Apple');
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from D_View where SALE in ('') or FRUIT in ('Apple');`